# Как отобразить имена пользователей?

Tags: php, mysql

Я использовал [эту статью](http://php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=039), все сделал, как там сказано, но мне еще надо знать, как сделать так, чтобы для зарегистрированных пользователей было написано имя, кто онлайн;
а вот [система регистрации](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=506), которую я задействовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте таблицу *users* со списком всех пользователей. Кроме полей типа *id,login,pass* добавьте поле *last_visit* тип поля *timestamp*, значение по умолчанию записывайте туда *current_timestamp*, это все в бд при создании поля можно указать.
Теперь для того чтобы посчитать сколько человек онлайн и получить их данные делаем запрос:

```
$time=time();
$sql_sel='SELECT COUNT(t_user.id) AS `online_count`,t_user.* FROM `users` AS `t_user` WHERE last_time > $time-$wine';
```

Таким образом вы получите одним запросом количество онлайн и их данные. 
Считаю что ненадо создавать для этого создаваит еще таблицу, специально чтоб посчитать количество онлайн и нагружать базу лишними запросами. просто добавьте одно поле в существующую бд пользователей и сделайте такой запрос

Comment: вылазиет ошибка

Comment: Ошибка
SQL-запрос:

CREATE TABLE  `host1235767`.`qwerty` (

`qwerty` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

Ответ MySQL: 

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'qwerty'

Comment: Заходите в phpmyadmin, выбираете свою таблицу, выбираете вкладку структура. Внизу есть добавить поле в таблицу, берете в конец таблицы. нажимаете ок.поле - last_time, тип - timestamp, default - current_timestamp.
Прошу прощения, указал не верный типа поля, надо не datetime, а timestamp
CREATE TABLE host1235767.qwerty (

qwerty TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

Comment: пробовал но эффекта не дало

Comment: Что именно щас не получилось? добавить поле или сделать выборку? 
Почитайте про типы данных mysql - http://mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html